# Using relativeTo from a guard on multiple feature modules

Tags: angular

I have two lazily loaded Feature Modules that follow the same flow (1. Select, 2. Review, 3. Confirm). I want to guard the Review step and navigate back to Select with one Guard for both Modules. This means the navigate rule will have to understand the context of the Module you're currently in and navigate you to either `/enroll/select` or `/change/select` respectively. I thought I could achieve this with the `relativeTo` property but I'm getting the following error.

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'select' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'select'`

Here is a [StackBlitz with a minimally reproduced example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gqm77s?file=src/app/app.module.ts).

```
const appRoutes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'enroll',
    loadChildren: () => import('./enroll.module').then((m) => m.EnrollModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'change',
    loadChildren: () => import('./change.module').then((m) => m.ChangeModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

```
const enrollRoutes = [
  { path: 'select', component: EnrollSelectComponent },
  { path: 'review', component: EnrollReviewComponent, canActivate: [MyGuard] },
  { path: 'confirm', component: EnrollConfirmComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

```
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  canActivate() {
    this.router.navigate(['select'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your guard to the following should make it work:

```
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        this.router.navigate([state.root.firstChild.url.toString(), 'select']);
        return false;
     }
}
```

**Short explanation:**

Injecting the ActivatedRoute didnt work as you expected. The route always was the '' route. But you can work with the snapshot attributes I added to the canActivate method. Unfortunately I didnt get it to work with relativeTo, since it relies on an ActivatedRoute (not on a snapshot).

Comment: That certainly works, I wish there were a more eloquent solution that didn't involve drilling down so deep into RouterState though. I still also don't fully understand why the route is `''` and not `'enroll'`.

Comment: A guard is kind of top early for an activatedRoute. In fact its not yet activated. It will maybe get avtivated depending on the result of the guard. The documentation of activatedRoute says its available for components.